# Getting Info out of a custom control with jQuery. Visual Studio 2010

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

I am learning Web Applications development with Microsoft .NET Framework 4. While I am going through the book, I have a side project at work that I am coding while I learn this stuff.

It is a real simple application that, based on a username, it will query a database, dynamically create custom controls based on the number of rows from the database.

The custom control is nothing more than a image and a label. It does however have some member variables: reportName and filePath.

```
public partial class ReportIcon : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public string reportName { get; set; }
    public string filePath { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReportNameLabel.Text = this.reportName;
    }
}
```

These dynamically created icons are created just fine and the member variables are set according to the database values.

I am trying to retrieve the filePath value using jQuery's onClick event. I can't seem to be able to get to that information. Right now I just have it alerting that the icon was indeed clicked.

```
$('.report-icons').click(
    function () {
        $(this).siblings().removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        alert("Get PDF File");
    }

);
```

Can someone point me in the right direction to get to this information in the custom control using jQuery?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You would need to write the filepath out into a UI control that could then be accessed by JQuery i.e.

**Markup**

```
<asp:Label runat=server ID="lblFilePath" />
```

**Code behind**

```
lblFilePath.Text = filePath
```

**JQuery**

```
alert($(#<%=lblFilePath.ClientID%>).text());
```

or use a hidden field or leverage data attributes of a control. The principle will be similar

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that you do not want your users to see the file path. Crab Bucket's method would definitely work, but I would suggest using a hidden control instead of a label control.

**HTML**

< asp:Hidden runat="server" id="filePath"/>

**CodeBehind**

filePath.value = myReportPath

**JQuery**

alert($("#<%=filePath.ClientID %>").val());

Comment: What am I doing wrong?

<b>HTML</b>
<asp:HiddenField ID="FilePathHiddenField" runat="server" />

Code Behind
FilePathHiddenField.Value = this.filePath;

JQuery
alert($("#<%=FilePathHiddenField.ClientID%>").val());

The alery is empty. If I use a label then the alert box says #<%=FilePathLabel.ClientID%>

Comment: the IDs i.e. FilePathHiddenField are case sensitive - that could be it

Comment: Copied straight from the source to JQuery.

Comment: When looking at the source, the id for the hidden fieldss that are dynamical created are "ContentPlaceHolder1_ReportListView_ctl00_FilePathHiddenField", ContentPlaceHolder1_ReportListView_ctl01_FilePathHiddenField, ContentPlaceHolder1_ReportListView_ctl02_FilePathHiddenField, etc.

Comment: try changing .val() to length in your alert to make sure that you are successfully selecting something.

Comment: it comes back as 0. This is really interesting because if I use a label instead of a hidden field, I get it to return the string "<%=FilePathHiddenField%>", which is not correct also. I am thinking it has to do with these controls being dynamically created, assigned an ID at run time and that they are in a content placeholder. Anyone else have any suggestions on how I can get this information out? Stuck in the water until I figure it out.

Comment: You should be able to access the control whether it is hidden or not because it is a control on the form regardless of visibility. You are right about the dynamically created name. That is why you should use "<%=FilePathHiddenField.ClientID%>". Work with your selector to find out what you are selecting. Try something like $("input [type=hidden]"). That should return all hidden fields. Reference http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ to get a better feel for selectors. Play around with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a data-filepath attribute to the generated HTML element, which you could then read using jquery.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I am really new at this :)